# How to write all three values using the resxresourcewriter?

Tags: asp.net, resources, localization, resx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.aspx

In this link and others like it, I see code to write in the "name" and "value" but not the "comment". I use the comment field heavily. Is there code for accessing all 3 simultaneously or the comment field individually? Or do I have to manipulate the XML directly?

Comment: Does anybody use the ResxResourceWriter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently you can set the comment on a `ResXDataNode` object. You can then write the ResXDataNode with the `ResXResourceWriter.AddResource(ResXDataNode)` method.

```
resxWriter.AddResource(new ResXDataNode("key", "value") { Comment="comment" });
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ResxSync.aspx?msg=1708100 (after the main article, comment "Comments ARE accesible [modified]")

Comment: This works for above C# 2.0 releases. So to use it in C# 2.0 I used the following. `ResXDataNode dataNode = new ResXDataNode("key", "value"); dataNode.Comment = "Comment"; resxWriter.AddResource(dataNode);`